# How to calculate $\int \frac{\sinh \left(x\right)}{\cosh \left(x\right)-\cos \left(y\right)}dy$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to calculate $$\int \frac{\sinh \left(x\right)}{\cosh \left(x\right)-\cos \left(y\right)}dy$$ I know that the answer is $2\arctan\left(\coth\frac{x}{2}\cdot\tan\frac{y}{2}\right)$ but don't have idea how to get it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

Put $$t=\tan(\frac y2)$$
with
$$\cos(y)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

and

$$dy=2\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$

it becomes

$$\int \frac{2\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=$$

$$\int \frac{2\sinh(x)dt}{\cosh(x)-1+t^2(\cosh(x)+1)}$$

Remember that
$$\cosh(x)-1=2\sinh^2(\frac x2),$$

$$\cosh(x)+1=2\cosh^2(\frac x2)$$
and
$$\sinh(x)=2\sinh(\frac x2)\cosh(\frac x2)$$

Now, with the substitition $$u=t\cosh(\frac x2)$$, you will get the result.